# How to make all routes go to index?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm developing a single page app and I want to know how to make all routes go to index?

Comment: Wow, seriously? More details, please. What's your server layout? What's your index?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
app.get('*', ...
```

if you are using express ;)

Comment: One more detail: if you using `express.static`, make sure it goes **before** `app.router` in cofiguration.